# How to access the contents of an iframe using jQuery or javascript

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that loads a page which, when a button is clicked, loads dynamic content including links.  I need to change the target of all these links from `_blank` to `_self` - but I'm completely stuck on how to get the code to run each time the new content is loaded in the iframe.  I've tried lots of options, the latest being to add a click function to the iframe as a trigger to run the code:

```
$("#myFrame").click(function () {
  $('#myFrame').find('a[target="_blank"]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('target', '_self');
  });
});
```

How do find the dynamically generated content and change the link targets once the content has finished loading in the iframe?  There is no 'same origin policy' issue, as the page in the iframe is on the same domain.

Thanks.

Comment: can you create http://jsfiddle.net/ for what you tried so far so that we can figure out the exact problem and solve it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javaScript to get the DOM of your iframe like this:

```
var doc=window.frames[ "yourFrameName" ].document
```

**NOTE:** Use `name` not `id` or `class` of your frame if you are following above rule to get the DOM of your frame

change this to jquery object

```
var elem=$(doc);
```

now bind click event on `elem` as you are doing in code in your question

```
elem.click(function () {

 elem.find('a[target="_blank"]').each(function () {

  $(this).attr('target', '_self');
 });

});
```

Comment: I realised I'd left something out - the iframe itself is loaded by first selecting one of a number of links, so at page load it is empty.  By wrapping your code in a frame onload function, it works perfectly.  Even better, I understand exactly what you've done.  Thanks for a very clear lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can use contents() method

Here is an example :

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")
```