# from iframe page event change css of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `homepage` containing middle_overlay div which is initially not visible .Also , it contains"`iframe capture`" there is click button on page,on click event of button i want to make middle_overlay div  visible, but from  another page can i change how can i change css?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="middle_overlay">
</div>

<div id="middle">
    <iframe id="middle_frame" src="capture.php" frameborder='0' border='0' style="border:0;" seamless>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

JQuery ::

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#Monthly_Report').click(function(){
alert('monthly report clicked');
$('#middle_overlay').css('display','block');                                

});



});
```

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: @palasH have added js code please check

Comment: $('#Monthly_Report') is in iframe try alert $('#Monthly_Report').parents('iframe').attr('id'). If you can get that you can get to the parent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.parent.$('#middle_overlay').css('display','block');
```

Note this will only work if your iframe and parent page are from the same domain.

Comment: @simmisimmi excellent. Mark it as the answer then so I get a nice big green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this jquery solution also:

```
$("#middle_frame").contents().find('#Monthly_Report').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#middle_overlay').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have got your answer, but you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19423398/1642219,  to get more clear view of your problem