# jQuery Changing child elements within iFrame content

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame which shows an Excel file saved as html (same domain). I call it like this:

```
<iframe id="nieuws" src="nieuws.htm" seamless ></iframe>
```

I would like to show the hyperlinks in the Excel.html the same as all my others. All links in Excel are formatted with the SPAN tag within the A tag. Like this:

```
<a href="http://[HYPERLINK]">
<span style='font-size:12.0pt'>[TEXT HERE]</span>
</a>
```

So I do:

```
$('#nieuws').contents().find('a > span').css('font-size', '10pt');
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Show us your **Iframe HTML**

Comment: until unless you show us your iframe html , we cant help

Answer (score 0):

each iframe on the page has its own DOM that is the iframe tag is part of your current page not its content (because its content is another document).

i have answered this type of question here.You can refactor the code according to your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/19423398/1642219

**EDIT**

```
<iframe id="nieuws" src="nieuws.htm" onload=load()></iframe>

function load()
{
  var frm=document.getElementById('nieuws')

  var frmdoc=frm.contentDocument || frm.contentWindow.document;

  $(frmdoc).find('a span').css('font-size', '10pt')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I get it to run in IE, but not in Chrome. The very first line doesn't give any result in Chrome. 'var doc=window.frames[ "yourFrameName" ].document' gives null to doc. Do you have the same experience? (yes I do replace yourFrameName)

Comment: chrome and opera have same-origin and same-domain issues but i don't think that's the problem as you have mentioned that both main window and iframe contents are from same domain. However i have edited the answer and I have tested this on my computer's localhost.I hope this will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.getElementById('iframename').contentWindow.document.body).find('font').attr("face", "Tahoma")
```

Comment: Eould be great if you could elaborate a bit on your answer. E.g. what's the problem with OPs code and why your snippet is a solution to his problem.